# Python- executing code lines after host force closing

Tags: python

I want to execute a code line when the host forces program to close.

This is the situation I have:

```
server = Server()
try:
    server.open()
    while True:
        server.run()
finally:
    server.close()
```

The while loop runs forever and changing it will be a huge pain in the ass(if it is even possible).

Is it possible?